# Finding a defective Corner[circled] from contours

Tags: opencv

I want to find the corners of a object & detect if there is a cut in the corner. The Real Image is so Big & it consist of lot of noise inside the Contour Area. So far I've tried... 
1)find the contours 
2)approximate the contour to find the approximate corners points 
3)crop each corner image & compare it with cvMatchShapes() Rotated @ Corners.

But the results was not accurate & i need some guidance.Here is the sample canny output image for which i wanna detect the Cut which is CIRCLED. Also in real Image I'm getting lot of noise in the canny output so Pls suggest me how to detect this shape defect at Corners. 
![enter image description here][1]Regards, Balaji.R

http://answers.opencv.org/question/25730/finding-a-defective-cornercircled-from-contours/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you do the step 3, you may want to do [hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). OpenCV function can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/shape/doc/shape_distances.html#hausdorffdistanceextractor). I think hausdoff distance best suites your requirement. Find the distance between the corners and if the distance is more than a certain value, then it is defective. It can also take care of noise upto certain extent.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @Pavan Kumar Perali. I'm still having difficulty detecting the defective corner because it further adds some shapes around the corner. I've updated the Image in the link. I'm looking forward to have any suggestions on this image.http://answers.opencv.org/question/25730/finding-a-defective-cornercircled-from-contours/

Comment: It might help if you post the original images before doing the canny edge detector.

Comment: Like the IC's in this Image link. I need to detect Notches in the IC. the Notch position may vary with respect to type of IC. http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MME_IC_top.jpg

Comment: If detecting the Notch is the goal, you may try pattern match using NCC (normalized cross correlation - CvMatchTemplate)  Compared to solving this problem using edges, it is much robust. suppose you have a cut in one corner of a rectangle shape image. Take the 4 corners (I hope you can position the corners approximately) and match them with each other. the one which matches by least Normalized correlation score with all others is the Notch. You can make similar logic for other notch types. (I am not sure this suggestion helps you, but just occuured to me!)